Difficult Web scraping a dynamic content website with R
library(readr)
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

salary_link <- "https://www.spotrac.com/mlb/rankings/salary/pitching/"
salary_page <- read_html(salary_link)
salaries <- html_text(html_elements(salary_page, ".info"))
teams <- html_text(html_elements(salary_page, ".rank-position"))

When I try to scrape the data from this site I only get the first 100 elements when there is supposed to be 308 on the page.
I tried webscraping with rvest but through some searching I know I have to do something with R Selenium. If you could help introduce this to be it would be greatly appreciated.

Fortunately, in rvest_1.0.4 they introduced read_html_live(). It behaves similarly-enough that you can use it in-place and get what you need.
salary_page <- rvest::read_html_live(salary_link)

FYI, you can grab the individual components as you want:
salaries <- html_elements(salary_page, ".info") |> html_text()
teams <- html_elements(salary_page, ".rank-position") |> html_text()
out <- data.frame(salary = salaries, teams = trimws(teams))
head(out)
#          salary teams
# 1 $70,000,000     LAD
# 2 $43,333,334     TEX
# 3 $43,333,333     HOU
# 4 $40,000,000     TEX
# 5 $36,000,000     NYY
# 6 $35,416,670     WSH

or you can get the whole table, with a little bit of effort:
out <- html_node(salary_page, "table") |> html_table()
out <- out[!is.na(out$Player) & nzchar(out$Player), nzchar(colnames(out))]
head(out)
# # A tibble: 6 × 5
#   Player                                                                                                                                                 POS     Age Throws salary     
#   <chr>                                                                                                                                                  <chr> <int> <chr>  <chr>      
# 1 "Ohtani\n\t\t\t\n            \t\n            \n                                \n            \n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\tShohei Ohtani\n\t\t\t\t\t  LAD"       SP/DH    29 R      $70,000,000
# 2 "Scherzer\n\t\t\t\n            \t\n            \n                                \n            \n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\tMax Scherzer\n\t\t\t\t\t  TEX"      SP       39 R      $43,333,334
# 3 "Verlander\n\t\t\t\n            \t\n            \n                                \n            \n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\tJustin Verlander\n\t\t\t\t\t  HOU" SP       41 R      $43,333,333
# 4 "deGrom\n\t\t\t\n            \t\n            \n                                \n            \n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\tJacob deGrom\n\t\t\t\t\t  TEX"        SP       36 R      $40,000,000
# 5 "Cole\n\t\t\t\n            \t\n            \n                                \n            \n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\tGerrit Cole\n\t\t\t\t\t  NYY"           SP       33 R      $36,000,000
# 6 "Corbin\n\t\t\t\n            \t\n            \n                                \n            \n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\tPatrick Corbin\n\t\t\t\t\t  WSH"      SP       34 L      $35,416,670

out2 <- strcapture("^([^\n]*)\n(.*)\n([^\n]*)$", out$Player, 
                   list(last="", full="", team="")) |>
  lapply(trimws) |>
  as.data.frame() |>
  cbind(out[,-1])
head(out2)
#        last             full team   POS Age Throws      salary
# 1    Ohtani    Shohei Ohtani  LAD SP/DH  29      R $70,000,000
# 2  Scherzer     Max Scherzer  TEX    SP  39      R $43,333,334
# 3 Verlander Justin Verlander  HOU    SP  41      R $43,333,333
# 4    deGrom     Jacob deGrom  TEX    SP  36      R $40,000,000
# 5      Cole      Gerrit Cole  NYY    SP  33      R $36,000,000
# 6    Corbin   Patrick Corbin  WSH    SP  34      L $35,416,670

(And I think there are more than 308 on the page, this load shows 574, where the read_html() non-live version pulled 106 or so.)

I recently installed Rselenium on Windows 10 referencing these old instructions. Basically:

Install RSelenium. install.packages("RSelenium")
Then do several steps to ensure the RSelenium dependency rJava is installed. This was:


Download and install version of Java your specific system.
Download and install version of JAVA JDK for your specific system.
Install rJava install.packages("rJava")
Set your JAVA_HOME environment. For me this was done in R with Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22\")
Restart computer.

At this point you are pretty much ready to start using RSelenium. I happen to have Firefox installed on my computer already and use that as the 'browser'. Here is a working example that creates a data frame from the site you mentioned:
library(RSelenium)

# Start the RSelenium server and browser. Port must be an integer. 
rD <- RSelenium::rsDriver(browser="firefox", port=4551L, verbose=F, chromever = NULL)

#open Firefox
rD$client$open

#Go to the pitching site
rD$client$navigate("https://www.spotrac.com/mlb/rankings/salary/pitching/")

#Select what you want by css selector
string<- rD$client$findElement(using = "css selector", "#main")$getElementText()
string<-string |> as.character()

#only keep the information about the players
string<-strsplit(x= string,"\nTHROWS\nSALARY\n")[[1]][[2]]

#Split string by new line
records <- unlist(strsplit(string, split = "\\n(?=\\d+\\n)", perl = TRUE))
#remove the player rank since it is not consistently shown for each player 
records<- sub("^\\d+\\n", "", records)
#split rest of the details on to their own line
records<-unlist(strsplit(records, split = "\\n", perl = TRUE))
#remove leading/ trailing whitespace
records<- records|> trimws()
#remove any empty strings
records<-records[records != ""]

#logical vectors patterned after information order
Name<- c(T,F,F)
Team<- c(F,T,F)
Other_Details<- c(F,F,T)

#data fame of pitcher data
result<- data.frame(name = records[Name],
           team = records[Team],
           details = records[Other_Details])

This gives result of:
                name team                details
1          Shohei Ohtani  LAD SP/DH 29 R $70,000,000
2           Max Scherzer  TEX    SP 39 R $43,333,334
3       Justin Verlander  HOU    SP 41 R $43,333,333
4           Jacob deGrom  TEX    SP 36 R $40,000,000

This is just one possible workflow. If you use a different css selector value (something other than #main) or do something other than grabbing the inner text (e.g. $getelementtext()) the cleaning you need to do will differ.
